# Recover webpage content from chrome cache

Tags: google-chrome, caching, recover

Sublime just erased all my html and save it to the server. I have gone to about:cache, unfortunately the only cached page I see is the blank one. Is there a way to see older cached versions of that page, maybe an older date. I spent countless hours working on this page.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, I believe you are hosed, unless you had that page live and indexed on Google and in Google Search Engine Results. I remember I had a client who needed content from a web page he had deleted, but Google still had a cached version of it in its SERPs.